# How to make a Snap application (ksnip) appear in "open with other application" context menu?

Tags: nautilus, snap, screenshot, file-association

For editing screengrabs, I prefer to use [ksnip](https://snapcraft.io/ksnip), since [Shutter](https://shutter-project.org/) was no longer installable without hassles on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04

However `ksnip` is available as a Snap App on my 20.04

```
○ → snap list | grep ksnip
ksnip                    1.8.0                       265    latest/stable    dporobic
```

Unfortunately I have to start ksnip from the command line, then use the File-Open Dialog to pick a screengrab/PNG, then edit it in ksnip. This is should be easier.

What I want is to use Nautilus File manager, then select the "Open with other Application" context menu item to select `ksnip`, and the have `ksnip` open the file I picked with nautilus.

Nautilus Context Menu, selecting a PNG:

[image: nautilus contextmenu]

"Select Application" Dialog:

[image: select app dialog]

**How can I achieve this?**

There is a "View all Applications" Button, but after clicking, `ksnip` does NOT appear in this list of apps. "Find new applications" does not work either.

Maybe this is a duplicate, but I think we did not have the combination yet (Hack the dialog *and* Snap App)

> (Note to self: maybe Shutter *is* usable again. Development had stalled for a while, or it needed *a lot* of deprecated versions of gnome libs as dependencies) .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nautilus right-click menu only picks up applications that are set to launch with an argument, the file name. The `.desktop` file that comes with the snap is not properly configured in that respect.

• Copy the supplied .desktop file, `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/ksnip_ksnip.desktop`, to your private `~/.local/share/applications` folder.
• Edit your new `~/.local/share/applications/ksnip_ksnip.desktop` with a text editor, and add `%U` after the command to execute the program, so it looks like:

```
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/ksnip_ksnip.desktop /snap/bin/ksnip %U
```

• Wait a little and try the right-click menu option of Files again. You may need to exit and restart Files. It should now be listed among your programs.

Comment: Thanks, this works! - I have also fixed the layout of your unordered list, it was all on a a single line for some reason

Comment: This solution does not work in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, in location /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications there is no ksnip_ksnip.desktop

Comment: Update 2023 for Ubuntu 22.10 (where *Shutter* is now also availbe as a snap) . I was able to do the same trick with the `shutter_shutter.desktop` file. (providing `%F instead of %U as an argument)

Answer (score 1):

In 22.10:

```
$ cp /usr/share/applications/org.ksnip.ksnip.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/org.ksnip.ksnip.desktop
```

Then add `%U` to the Desktop entry, like this:

```
$ gnome-text-editor ~/.local/share/applications/org.ksnip.ksnip.desktop
```

[image]

The Open File dialog will be updated immediately. You don't need to close it or restart Nautilus.

[image]

And with "Always use for this file type selected", ksnip will appear in the context menu:

[image]